# Error in geopandas module while running binary application of python script in linux

Tags: python, linux, pyinstaller, executable

When I run python script it is working fine but when tried to run executable of same python script made using pyinstaller then getting module error. Specifically getting error while importing geopanda module. The error coming is mentioned below:

```
ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_create_from_database: Cannot find proj.db
PROJ: proj_create_from_database: Cannot find proj.db
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ImageChecker.py", line 27, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
  File "geopandas/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
  File "geopandas/datasets/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
StopIteration
[7062] Failed to execute script 'ImageChecker' due to unhandled exception!
```

Comment: Did you specify that `proj.db` should be included in your executable?

Comment: But my script doesn't require or contains any project.db database, then also it is giving error message.

Comment: It seems to a database of world map projections.  It must be present on your system, but you may need to set the PROJ_LIB environment variable to its location.  You will have to do some web searching.